# Bootstrap dropdown menu within a responsive table

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Im having an issue with a dropdown menu within a responsive table in Bootstrap 3. No matter what I place in the CSS (like overflow: auto or positioning) the menu in the dropdown appears within the responsive div and in order to click on any of the links you would have to scroll.

[image]

[image]

```
<div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-striped">
              <thead>
                <tr class="table_desc">
                  <th></th>
                  <th><input type="checkbox"></th>
                  <th>Status</th>
                  <th>Action</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <tr class="table_items">
                  <td><div class="item_strip"></div></td>
                  <th><input type="checkbox"></th>
                  <td>Deposit Paid</td>
                  <td>
                    <!-- Split button -->
                    <div class="btn-group action-button">
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger">View</button>
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                        <span class="caret"></span>
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
                      </button>
                      <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Edit</a></li>
                        <!-- <li class="divider"></li> -->
                        <li><a href="#">Send Invoice</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Send Reminder</a></li>
                      </ul>
                    </div>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
</div>
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: I answered to that in an other post:
[View my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26018756/bootstrap-button-drop-down-inside-responsive-table-not-visible-because-of-scroll#34211851)

Comment: @BaltazarQc Your solution doesn't work if you also want a vertical scrollbar on the responsive table by setting overflow-y: auto.

Answer (score 2):

after debugging in bootstrap.css on line 2247

```
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
 .table-responsive {
   width: 100%;
   margin-bottom: 15px;
   overflow-x: auto;
   overflow-y: hidden;
   -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
   -ms-overflow-style: -ms-autohiding-scrollbar;
   border: 1px solid #ddd;
  }
```

If you comment both overflows it works properly.It doesn't work properly below width 767 because of the overflow properties if you simply overwrite those in your css it will work.