# Dropdown in dataTables

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, datatable

First of all, I tried to resolved my problem with

[Bootstrap button drop-down inside responsive table not visible because of scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26018756/bootstrap-button-drop-down-inside-responsive-table-not-visible-because-of-scroll)

and

[Bootstrap dropdown menu within a responsive table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27081082/bootstrap-dropdown-menu-within-a-responsive-table)

but no way has functioned.

**Issue** : When I click on gear button I want that the dropdown appears above the dataTables and not IN the table.

Note that my table is a dataTables (https://datatables.net) initialized like that

```
$('#table_fours_send').DataTable({
    responsive: true,
    scrollX: true,
    sScrollX: '100%',
    paging: false,
    dom: 't<"margin-dataTable-bottom"<"pull-left margin-dataTable-pagination">>'
});
```

[image: problem]

Html code for my dropdown button

```
    <div class="form-group col-sm-2 no-padding-left no-padding-right">
        <div class="dropdown inline-block">
            <i class="fa fa-cog fa-lg padding-gear pointer dropdown-toggle" id="dropdownSend" 
               data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true"></i>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="dropdownSend">
                <li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#m_add_contact">{{'label.add_contact'|trans()}}</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#m_add_update_contact">{{'label.update_contact'|trans()}}</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>            
    </div>
```

**The better result** is from the first link (https://stackoverflow.com/a/34211851/5027172)
[image]

**But** I don't want to push with padding but rather showing the dropdown above the table.

Any ideas ? Needs more informations ?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried `z-index`  ?

Comment: Yes, on all node to be sure, no results

Comment: Maybe your parent container have a lower height. Try to increase it. Or play with overflow properties

Comment: For use z-index, your element must have a `position:relative;` or absolute. Try with this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After some hours I finally found the solution

The scrolling X of the plugin dataTables is responsible for this act !

```
t_fournisseurs_send = $('#table_fours_send').DataTable({
    responsive: true,
    scrollX: true,
    sScrollX: '100%',
    paging: false,
    dom: 't<"margin-dataTable-bottom"<"pull-left margin-dataTable-pagination">>'
});
```

to

```
t_fournisseurs_send = $('#table_fours_send').DataTable({
    responsive: true,
    paging: false,
    dom: 't<"margin-dataTable-bottom"<"pull-left margin-dataTable-pagination">>'
});
```

I hope that this can help some users of dataTables with dropdown.

Have a nice day.

Comment: I was just wondering this solution will disable the pagination and searching options. how can i enable both paging and searching while implementing the `dom`?

Answer (score 2):

After reviewing @quakes answer, there are some minor changes to respective code that will remove the unwanted created html at bottom of the page along with padding.

```
// Find the actual .dropdown-menu
        var $dropdown = $container.find('.dropdown-menu');
        if ($dropdown.length) {
            // Save a reference to it, so we can find it after we've attached it to the body
            $container.data('dropdown-menu', $dropdown);
        } else {
            $dropdown = $container.data('dropdown-menu');
        }

        $dropdown.css('top', ($container.offset().top + $container.outerHeight()) + 'px');
        $dropdown.css('left', $container.offset().left + 'px');
        $dropdown.css('position', 'absolute');
        $dropdown.css('display', 'block');
        $dropdown.appendTo('body');
    });

    $(document).on('hide.bs.dropdown', '.table-responsive', function (e) {
        // Hide the dropdown menu bound to this button
        $(e.target).data('dropdown-menu').remove();
    });
```

Comment: Refer to the link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34211851/5027172)

Comment: Ah, ok, thanks! You may put that into your answer, so that is is clearer.