# Dropdown inside datatable elements with pagination

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, datatable, pagination

I am new to data-tables and I am trying to do [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36596327/dropdown-in-datatables?noredirect=1&lq=1) but i wanted to do with pagination since the answer provided in the link did not involve any pagination. Is it possible? Because i have tried and when i set the pagination to true, the drop-down solution in the link given won't work.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#datatable-responsive').DataTable( {
        "responsive": true,
        "paging": true,
        "dom": 't<"margin-dataTable-bottom"<"pull-left margin-dataTable-pagination">>'
      } );
    } );
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this alternative solution which is an extensible pagination mechanism in datatable,

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
$('#example').DataTable( {
    "pagingType": "full_numbers"
} );
} );
```

Please find below link for more details:
https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/alt_pagination.html

Comment: that is not what i want. i meant, i want to display the dropdown inside the datatables without the scroll and the datatables will have pagination at the same time. Based on the link i've given, the solution does not work when there is pagination