# drop-down menu hiding behind the panel

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Bootstrap menu hide behind the panel, **no effect with z-index**:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <i class="fa fa-calendar fa-fw"></i> System Years
    <div class="pull-right">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-xs btn-add-year " data-toggle="tooltip" title="Add year"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- /.panel-heading -->
  <div class="panel-body">
    <div class="table-responsive">
      <table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <strong>2014</strong>

              <div class="btn-group">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-xs dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                                Menu 1 <span class="caret"></span>
                                            </button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li><a href="javascript:;">All</a></li>
                  <li><a href="javascript:;">Other</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>

            </td>

          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <strong>2015</strong>

              <div class="btn-group">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-xs dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                                Menu 2 <span class="caret"></span>
                                            </button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li><a href="javascript:;">All</a></li>
                  <li><a href="javascript:;">Other</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>

            </td>

          </tr>

        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    <!-- /.table-responsive -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.panel-body -->
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: I found solution about this [see solution][1] I hope this one helps to you... thank you


  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65614338/14344959

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Issue is related to overflow of a parent div. See following code for that div and see image for reference:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 767px)
tables.less:180
.table-responsive {
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    overflow-y: visible;
    -ms-overflow-style: -ms-autohiding-scrollbar;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    height: 120px;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can use `overflow: inherit !important;` inside .table-responsive div

```css
.table-responsive{overflow: inherit !important;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <i class="fa fa-calendar fa-fw"></i> System Years
    <div class="pull-right">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-xs btn-add-year " data-toggle="tooltip" title="Add year"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- /.panel-heading -->
  <div class="panel-body">
    <div class="table-responsive">
      <table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <strong>2014</strong>

              <div class="btn-group">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-xs dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                                Menu 1 <span class="caret"></span>
                                            </button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li><a href="javascript:;">All</a></li>
                  <li><a href="javascript:;">Other</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>

            </td>

          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <strong>2015</strong>

              <div class="btn-group">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-xs dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                                Menu 2 <span class="caret"></span>
                                            </button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li><a href="javascript:;">All</a></li>
                  <li><a href="javascript:;">Other</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>

            </td>

          </tr>

        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    <!-- /.table-responsive -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.panel-body -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

please use the class table instead of table-responsive. the table-responsive class has a property overflow:hidden.

```html
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <i class="fa fa-calendar fa-fw"></i> System Years
    <div class="pull-right">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-xs btn-add-year " data-toggle="tooltip" title="Add year"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- /.panel-heading -->
  <div class="panel-body">
    <div class="table">
      <table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <strong>2014</strong>

              <div class="btn-group">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-xs dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                                Menu 1 <span class="caret"></span>
                                            </button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li><a href="javascript:;">All</a></li>
                  <li><a href="javascript:;">Other</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>

            </td>

          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <strong>2015</strong>

              <div class="btn-group">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-xs dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                                Menu 2 <span class="caret"></span>
                                            </button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li><a href="javascript:;">All</a></li>
                  <li><a href="javascript:;">Other</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>

            </td>

          </tr>

        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    <!-- /.table-responsive -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.panel-body -->
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, can't do this ,we need table responsive

Comment: Ok, add this in .table-responsive { overflow-y: visible;}